# Cannot select an object in 2D Sheet

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a wall object that I can't select in 2D Sheet, they are other same wall type objects I can select and I noticed that for these the Viewables_in property has the sheets value.

I opened the model in revit 2017 and I don't see anything different for that wall I cant select.

[viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aURl7.jpg)

[revit_object_properties_non-selectable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAUgJ.jpg)

[revit_object_properties_selectable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIx25.jpg)

Comment: Could you consider providing a none confidential reproducible Revit model demonstrating this issue to forge [DOT] help [AT] autodesk [DOT] com?

Comment: We emailed you a link to download the model, keep us posted.

Comment: Thanks, I got your email, we will continue there in our Helpdesk system.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the reason for some elements are not selectable is because of this [limitation](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Revit-DocumentPresent/files/GUID-EDEA2E5D-6094-4B9D-A4E7-43C95A3E0615-htm.html).

However, I cannot make these wall elements be selectable after hiding annotations & grids, as well as turning view renderring off. Therefore, I logged a request as `RVTLMV-952` to our engineering team to allocate time to investigate. Please remember this request id for future reference.

You're welcome to provide additional information to us or track updates via sending emails to this channel quoting this id. Thanks!